# Calculating moment of inertia by integration

Tags: integration, mathematical-physics

To calculate the moment of inertia of arbitrary shape,

you have to integrate $dI$ for both $r$ and $\theta$

Basically $dI=dm r^2$  ,  $\int_0^R \int_0^\pi dr d\theta$ in polar coordinates.

If the total mass is M, then $dm=M\frac{(partial-area)}{(total-area)}$

I tried to integrate the following picture in the polar coordinate, only the light-blue colored part that looks like a fidget spinner.

[image]

but the integration was too hard.

Please help!

Comment: So to confirm, the fidget spinner has mass $M/2$?

Comment: If you're calculating the polar moment of inertia (about the $z$-axis), then for each of the three disks it'll be $\pi/2 + 4 \pi$ by the parallel axis theorem and for each of the six sectors of the central region it'll be
$$2 \int_0^{\pi/6} \int_0^{2 \cos \phi - \sqrt {1 - 4 \sin^2 \phi}}
 r^3 dr d\phi.$$

Answer (score 1):

Integration over the whole domain is not the easier option nor the recommended one. The body is a collection of six circles, so the momentum of inertia should be calculated as a sum of six (in this case equal) terms. Let $r$ be the radius of the circle and $m=M/6$ the mass of a *single* circle.
The momentum of inertia with respect to *the center of the circle* is
$$
I_1=\frac12 m r^2
$$
By the Huygens-Steiner theorem the momentum with respect to the origin $O$ is
$$
I_2=\frac12 m r^2+md^2
$$
where $d$ is the distance between the origin and the center of the circle. From the figure, it is apparent that $d=2r$, then
$$
I_2=\frac92 m r^2
$$
Therefore
$$
I=6 I_2=27mr^2=\frac92 M r^2
$$

Comment: However... there is an area inside too: im finding the only light-blue part.  That is why i used polar coordinate.

Comment: You should explain clearly what is the body whose momentum is to be calculated. The text is too incomplete, and the figure seems to indicate that you need the momentum of the six circles. Please, clarify the question

Comment: sorry sir I'm not good at English TT btw thanks for your answer :)